# Summing up a duration of timedates values

Tags: java, android, parsing, datetime

I have array of DateTime variables named endDate, startDate
I calculate the difference and the result is array of seconds.

I am looping trought the array and I calculate the diff

long diffInSec=endDate-startData...

and then I want to sum the difference in one variable like this
sum+=diffInSec;

and in the end I want to have something like this
sum= 1 mount 3 days 4 hours 5 min and 5 seconds

I know everything except the part of the sum.
What variable type should be the sum, is it DateTime ?
how do I add the seconds from variable that is of type long.

I hope I explains good the thing that I want to achieve, fell free to ask if something of the question is unclear

Comment: I'd advise you only ever go up as far as days, since the length of a month isn't fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it long and when you finally get the result, find out the amount of seconds, minutes etc by simple division. That's one way.

Although there could be a better solution if you can be more clear on what you are calculating.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Calendar and setting it up to January 1 0:00, then adding the milliseconds value and getting the Months, Day of the year, Hour and Minutes should work as long as it's less than twelve months.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2011, 1, 1, 0,0,0);
cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, sum);
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

...